# Magento 2 how to lock a customer account when it's in an specific group?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, customer-account, plugin

I have been searching how to lock a customer account but had no luck.
My idea is to create a customer group called Locked, and every customer that is assigned to that group will be locked.

I was thinking that a Plugin or Observer might work everytime I switch a customer to this group, but then how do I lock the account? is there something like
`$customerStatus = $customer->isLocked();` or a method that I can use to lock the customer?

Greetings!

Comment: What do you mean by "lock" a customer?  There isn't this functionality within Magento by default.  If you want to stop them being able to login, adding an observer /plugin around authentication would then work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use customer_login event observer to get customer group after login and then logout the customer in observer

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_login">
        <observer name="customer_login_observer" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\CustomerLogin" />
    </event>
</config>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Observer/CustomerLogin.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class CustomerLogin implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory
     */
    private $responseFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
     */
    private $url;
    private $customerSession;
    private $messageManager;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager
    ) {
        $this->responseFactory = $responseFactory;
        $this->url = $url;
        $this->customerSession= $customerSession;
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
    }
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
        $customerGroup = $customer->getGroupId();
        if($customerGroup=="locked"){
            $this->customerSession->logout();
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('You are Locked'));
            $redirectionUrl = $this->url->getUrl('set-your-redirect-url');
            $this->responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($redirectionUrl)->sendResponse();
            return $this;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was very close to the answer, this worked like a charm, just modify $customerSession->logout(); to $this->customerSession->logout();  , because there is no variable called $customerSession. Thank you very much!

Comment: ok I have updated my answer